# Is it possible to create union key value type from object type?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

For example I have object type

```
type FooBar = {
  foo: number,
  bar: string
}
```

and I want to create this type

```
{key: "foo", value: number} | {key: "bar", value: string}
```

I can create

```
{key: keyof FooBar}
```

and

```
{value: FooBar[keyof FooBar]}
```

But I want to combine them somehow.

Comment: `type FooBar = {key: "foo", value: number} | {key: "bar", value: string}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with a mapped type. Map each key to a `{key: <keyname>, value: <keytype>}` type, then build the union of all those using `keyof`:

```
type FooBar = {
  foo: number,
  bar: string
}

type KV<T> = {[K in keyof T]: {key: K, value: T[K]}}[keyof T];

declare const test: KV<FooBar>;
// `test` has type: {key: "foo", value: number} | {key: "bar", value: string}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [CRice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6293409/crice)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521690), the following snippet supports nested objects as well:

```js
type ObjectDeepValues<OBJ_T> = {
    [K in keyof OBJ_T]: OBJ_T[K] extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>
        ? ObjectDeepValues<OBJ_T[K]>
        : OBJ_T[K]
}[keyof OBJ_T];

const obj = {
    x: 5,
    b: true,
    nestedObj: {
        a: "hi",
    },
} as const;

type t1 = ObjectDeepValues<typeof obj>; // true | 5 | "hi"
```

([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AEQhMA1AhgGwFcIBnAHhgCEApAfQBUA+KAXigG8BYAKCj6gDaAaSgBLAHZQA1hBAB7AGawaDALoAuZXXrDVUCAA9gEcQBMSUAEoo5AJ1NkACrbmRboIbIA0UQuKnicgDu4ow8-BFQAPywiCjomDgExORU2rphvJF8mmkMujwAvgIy8kp59KoA3Dw8yHLiJMBQcoisHOH8BpoArF6dfHCawLbE-Vl84qTGpvAImlwTkbiaAEQAFqKr4xGF44VQuBb1jcA13DygkFDAAIztc-EYWHhEpGRXEIotiIxVUAB6AE3UbQAA+UB6UAhGy2QA))